# how to add the three beginning a unique class?

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="topunm">
<li><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test</a></li>
<li><a href="#">test</a></li>
</ul>
```

i want to add the number before the li. the following is my code:

```
$("ul.code-topnumb > li").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<span class="num">' + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
})
```

but now, i want to add a background to only the first three number. how to change the code? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?

```
$("ul.code-topnumb > li").each(function() {
    var cl;

    if($(this).index() < 3){
        cl = "num bgnd";
    }else{
        cl = "num";
    }

    $(this).prepend('<span class="' + cl + '">' + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
})
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to do something like this. You might want to change `prepend` to `before` though if you want your span to be outside the `li` tag. But I don't think it's valid to have a `<span>` directly in a `<ul>`

```
$("ul.topnum > li").each(function(i, el) {
    if(i < 3)
        $(el).css('background-color', '#0FF');
    $(el).prepend('<span class="num">' + (i+1) + "</span>");
})
```

Comment: It's prepend, so it will put the SPAN within the LI, not outside of it.

Comment: @Jared Farrish That's why I did it this way, but the OP said he was trying to put a number before each `<li>`.

Comment: Yes, but you're doing it the same way the OP suggests, so my assumption is that the OP's english may not be great. Regardless, using prepend with the LI being the selected element list will add the SPAN to the LI, not before it (and I thought the same thing you did at first).

Comment: @Jared Farish Yup... I just wasn't sure if that's what he wanted so I suggested that he change it to `before` if he really wants it outside the `<li>`

Comment: @Jared Farrish I think he wants all of them to have numbers prepended an just the first three to have the background color changed, so you still need to iterate through all the `<li>`s

Comment: whether the number is before the li or in the li. i used the css make them look the same.but if i want to use jquery to put the number before the li, which method should i use. thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [slice](http://api.jquery.com/slice/):

```
$(function(){
    $("ul.code-topnumb > li").slice(0, 3).each(function() {
        $(this).prepend('<span class="num">' + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
$("ul.code-topnumb > li").each(function() {
    $(this).prepend('<span class="num">' + ($(this).index() +1) + "</span>");
});

$('.num').slice(0,3).css('background-color', 'red');
```